# What is the easiest way to deploy the same desktop & software across 35 workstations for several hundred users?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, configuration-management

Currently we have 35 workstations with WIN XP SP3 on it. Currently they logon to Server 2012 Standard (we do have ability for RDS Session Based desktops), and the users files (my documents are stored on the server). Software is installed locally.

What is the easiest way for our school to be able to control each users desktop, and install software from the server, rather than what we're doing now.

IF we go the session based desktop route, how can we have it that on WIN XP when the user logins to the Domain they are doing a SSO to the session based desktop and that's all they see?

Comment: Of course this needs to be said: [Windows XP support has ended, and it's important to move to a supported operating system as soon as possible.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should employ Group Policy to be able to control and secure your schools computers.

As for them logging into RDP on the Server 2012, can you not just publish the software as a RemoteApp?  If they don't need a full desktop and they can open their files from the software, I think this would be a better solution.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10817.publishing-remoteapps-in-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to have users login normal through the domain, and upon login, they are presented with the remote app pop up screen?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to execute programs remotely and [Npackd](https://code.google.com/p/windows-package-manager/) to install software